# LIKE Query Not working Metamug

Tags: sql, metamug

I'm sending $q parameter for performing text search with `LIKE` as follows.
But I'm getting error in the json response.

```
<Query when="$type eq 'search'">
    SELECT name, rating FROM movie 
    WHERE name LIKE '%$q%'
</Query>
```

My API Call looks like this:

`https://api.metamug.com/appt/v1.0/movie?type=search&q=et`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't enclose the `$q` variable between `%` symbols the modulo must be the part of your `q` parameter's value during your request.
So your XML code must be like this

```
<Query when="$type eq 'search'">
    SELECT name, rating FROM movie 
    WHERE name LIKE $q
</Query>
```

And now while making a request encode the **modulo(%)** symbol so your request will look like this

https://api.metamug.com/appt/v1.0/movie?type=serach&q=%25et%25

PS: `% ==encoded==> %25`